# Link on image breaks table in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, hyperlink, html-table

I have a sliced up image inside a Photoshop generated table.
one of the slices has a link on it.
Displays fine in Safari and Chrome but the table breaks in Firefox: I have a slit a few pixels wide below the image.

Is there any way I can fix this?

This code is just the td which makes the whole thing whack:

```
<td colspan='3' background='wfimages/15.jpg'>
<a href='http://www.google.com'>
<img src='images/WorldFamous_01_05.png' width='490' height='490' border='0' alt=''>
</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Generic Statement; Please post your code first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hah, well, stupid me did not notice that the image was a slightly different size than the table cell. While safari made it look like everything is OK, firefox changed the size of the cell.

sorry!